# Iterate to find the repeat values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Window 10, Python 3.6

I have a dataframe df

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['boo', 'foo', 'too', 'boo', 'roo', 'too'],
                 'zip':['30004', '02895', '02895', '30750', '02895', '02895']})
```

I want to find the repeat record that has same 'name' and 'zip', and record the repeat times. The idea output is

```
  name repeat    zip
0  too      1  02895
```

Because my dataframe is much more than six rows, I need to use a iterate method. I appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) all columns and use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
#create DataFrame from online source
#df = pd.read_csv('someonline.csv')
#df = pd.read_html('someurl')[0]

#L = []
#for x in iterator:
    #in loop added data to list
#    L.append(x) 
##created DataFrame from contructor
#df = pd.DataFrame(L)

df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='repeat')
#if need specify columns
#df = df.groupby(['name','zip']).size().reset_index(name='repeat')
print (df)
  name    zip  repeat
0  boo  30004       1
1  boo  30750       1
2  foo  02895       1
3  roo  02895       1
4  too  02895       2
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jezrael. Great method! But I really need a iterate method, as the data is streaming in, and I need to pick out the repeated ones.

Comment: @datanew - So how is created DataFrame? Not sure if understand. There is many DataFrames?

Comment: @jezrarl - there are more rows. This six-row dataframe is my test data.

Comment: @datanew - Yes, but there is no problem if more rows, can you test it?

Comment: @jezrarl - it works. But I need a iterate method. Because the data is streaming in, it's not a fixed data set.

Comment: @datanew - so need in loop create one big Dataframe from streamed data? How are data streamed?

Comment: @jezrarl  - Yes. I need to assume the data is streaming, guess it is from some online data source.

Comment: @datanew - I am confused - From online data source is created dataframe, and then is used my solution. So what is difference between created Dataframe from online streamed data and data from lists or from csv?

Comment: @jezrarl - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a handy `.duplicated()` method that can help you identify duplicates.

```
df.duplicated()
```

By passing the duplicate vector into a selection you can get the duplicate record:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

You can get the sum of the duplicated records by using `.sum()`

```
df.duplicated().sum()
```